# Could not find developer disk image -xcode beta 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently downloaded a Xcode version 7.2 beta. when i try to run it on my iPhone it comes that the disk image could not be found.
any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: What is the ios version of your device.?

Comment: You need ios 9.2  beta version for testing

Answer (score 1):

Xcode beta 7.2 requires devices running iOS 9.2 to test applications.

Thanks.